# Definition of proportionality constant in Coulomb's law

Tags: electrostatics, coulombs-law, physical-constants, si-units, metrology

My textbook, which was written before 2019, says:

> $k$ [Coulomb's constant] is *defined* in terms of $c$ to be precisely $k=(10^{-7}\ {\rm N\cdot s^2/C^2)}c^2$

$\implies\displaystyle\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}=(10^{-7}\ {\rm N\cdot s^2/C^2)}{c^2}$ ------- (1)

Wikipedia tells me that:

$\epsilon_0$ is *defined* by the formula $\displaystyle\epsilon_0=\frac{1}{\mu_0c^2}$

$\displaystyle\implies\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}=\frac{\mu_0c^2}{4\pi}$

$\displaystyle\implies (10^{-7}\ {\rm N\cdot s^2/C^2)}c^2=\frac{\mu_0c^2}{4\pi}$ [Using (1)]

$\implies \mu_0=4\pi\times 10^{-7}\ {\rm N\cdot s^2/C^2}$ (exactly)

But Wikipedia also says this is no longer true (since 2019). So, is my textbook outdated? If so, what is the new definition of $k$ (Coulomb's constant)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the redefinition of SI units in 2019 (when the values of $e$ and $h$ were fixed as defined quantities), $\mu_0$ is an **experimentally determined** constant, its value being proportional to the dimensionless fine-structure constant, which is known to a relative uncertainty of about $1.5\times 10^{−10}$, with no other dependencies with experimental uncertainty.
Its value in SI units as recommended by CODATA 2018 (published in May 2019) is:
$μ_0 = 1.25663706212(19)\times 10^{−6}\,\rm H/m$ and this value may change in the future when further experimentation is performed.
This value is significantly different at about $3.6\,\sigma $  from the previous defined value $μ_0 = 4\pi\times 10^{−7}= 1.25663706143...\times 10^{−6}\rm\,H/m$.  However, for most of us this value is close enough to be used in everyday calculations.
The value of $\epsilon _0$ can then be found from the relationship $\epsilon_0=\dfrac{1}{\mu_0c^2}$ using the experimental value of $\mu_0$ and the defined value of $c=299792458\,\rm  m/s$.

Comment: But I'm looking for the value of $k$. Is $k=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}$ an exact definition?

Comment: Yes, why should it not be with its numerical value slightly different? [Coulomb constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law#Coulomb_constant)

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer as I don't have sufficient rep.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2019 units are defined not on their on but rather as how they can be calculated from 7 fundamental constants. Here the fundamental constants at play are the speed of light in the vacuum and the charge of the electron (although in the measurement of force you need mass and implies using the Planck constant as well). The Coulomb constant has units that can be written from those more fundamental constants so $\epsilon_o, \mu_o$ do not need to be set, they can be calculated. You can check  https://www.bipm.org/en/measurement-units/si-defining-constants or the related wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_redefinition_of_the_SI_base_units